# Can you change new Date().toUTCString() to milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970?

Tags: javascript, syntax, utc, gettime

I know how to change new Date() to UTC time by doing 
new Date().toUTCString()
But I want to take it a step further by getting the UTC time and THEN changing it into milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970.

I tried

```
new Date().toUTCString().getTime()
```

but it says that .getTime() is not a function for the date after it is converted to UTC time.
Is there any real solution?

Comment: For any serious time/date manipulation in JS you should have a look at [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: `toUTCString()` returns a *string* not a Date, hence why you can't call `getTime` on it.  Considering that date would be equivalent to the Unix timestamp from `getDate`, I don't understand what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

why not just new Date().getTime()? the .toUTCString will make it non Date object. so the getTime() will not work

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running getTime() method on string resulted from `new Date().toUTCString()`.

Try to use : 
`new Date(new Date().toUTCString()).getTime()`

Comment: This does return an integer of milliseconds, but oddly it still returns milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970 for my local time(EST). I am wanting to receive milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970 for UTC time. Unbiased as to which timezone I am in, or (which timezone client side browser is in)

Answer (score 0):

The `Date` object already is in "milliseconds since epoch", which is in UTC. So you just need to prevent string conversion. F.ex. using [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) on my Linux machine I get:

```sh
$ node
> new Date() * 1
1564721436203
> 

# cutting off the ...203 milliseconds
$ LC_ALL=C date --date @1564721436 --utc
Fri Aug  2 04:50:36 UTC 2019
```

But for any serious date/time manipulation in JS I would recommend [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: "But for any serious date/time manipulation in JS I would recommend Moment.js." Libraries come and go and Momentjs is not maintained any more.